# c# how to trim null elements at the start and end of a list

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

given a list of objects whose values are for

```
StatusList = new List<StatusData>
                {
                    new StatusData {Count = 0, Id = 1},
                    new StatusData {Count = 0, Id = 2},
                    new StatusData {Count = 1, Id = 3},
                    new StatusData {Count = 0, Id = 4},
                    new StatusData {Count = 2, Id = 5},
                    new StatusData {Count = 3, Id = 6},
                    new StatusData {Count = 0, Id = 7},
                    new StatusData {Count = 0, Id = 8},
                    new StatusData {Count = 0, Id = 2}
                };
```

how do i trim the left side and right side of the list by removing the elements with zeros?

Comment: What about the fourth element there? should that be removed too?

Comment: the fourth element is not removed..if it was then it would just require removing all elements where count is zero.

Answer (score 4):

```
int start = 0, end = StatusList.Count - 1;

while (start < end && StatusList[start].Count == 0) start++;
while (end >= start && StatusList[end].Count == 0) end--;

return StatusList.Skip(start).Take(end - start + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
var nonEmptyItems = StatusList.Where(sd => sd.Count > 0);
```

`nonEmptyItems` will contain the items with `Count` greater than 0, including the middle one.

Alternatively, if you don't want that central item removed, you can use a while loop and remove each empty item from the front and back till non such items exist.

```
var trimmed = false;
while(!trimmed)
{
  if(StatusList[0].Count == 0)
     StatusList.RemoveAt(0);

  if(StatusList[StatusList.Count - 1].Count == 0)
    StatusList.RemoveAt(StatusList.Count - 1);

  if(StatusList[0].Count == 0 > StatusList[StatusList.Count - 1].Count > 0)
    trimmed = true;
}
```

Comment: @RoeeGavirel - Yes. I stated that.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel - I find many times people don't post exactly what they are after.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Remove until count != 0 is found
foreach (var item in StatusList.ToArray())
{
    if (item.Count == 0)
        StatusList.Remove(item);
    else
        break;
}
// Reverse the list
StatusList.Reverse(0, StatusList.Count);
// Remove until count != 0 is found
foreach (var item in StatusList.ToArray())
{
    if (item.Count == 0)
        StatusList.Remove(item);
    else
        break;
}
// reverse back
StatusList.Reverse(0, StatusList.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite efficient but more readable solution would be:

```
StatusList.Reverse();
StatusList = StatusList.SkipWhile(x => x.Count == 0).ToList();
StatusList.Reverse();
StatusList = StatusList.SkipWhile(x => x.Count == 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved it...

```
RemoveOutsideZeros(ref StatusList);
                StatusList.Reverse();
RemoveOutsideZeros(ref StatusList);


private void RemoveOutsideZeros(ref List<StatusData> StatusList)
{
    bool Found0 = false;
    foreach (StatusData i in StatusList.ToList())
    {
        if (i.Count != 0)
    {
        Found0 = true;
    }
        if (i.Count == 0 && Found0 == false)
        {
            StatusList.Remove(i);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: your solution will throw an exception for empty list and for the list which has only items with Count = 0